# Cantor's Theorem with both finite and infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand the proof for Cantor's theorem. With the general proof, one takes a function $$f: A \rightarrow P(A)$$, and then assumes that the function is surjective, then utilizes the set $$S: \{x \in A: x \notin f(x)\}$$ in order to reach a contradiction.

However, suppose we have $A = \{1,2,3\}$. Then also suppose that $f(1) = \{2,3\}$, $f(2) = \{1,3\}$, and $f(3) = \{1,2\}$. In this example, as per my flawed understanding, it seems that a mapping has been constructed such that for each $x \in A$, there is a set B which is the result of $f(x)$ such that $B= \{x: x \in A, x \notin f(x)\}$.

There clearly isn't a bijection, however, I am wondering where my understanding is flawed as per the "existence" of the set S?

I know that I am mistaken in this and would truly appreciate any help to understand where the true contradiction would lie. I really appreciate any and all help regarding this.

Comment: If $S$ couldn't exist, then that would be a flaw in Cantor's argument.  Its existence isn't the problem.  It just cannot be in the range of $f$.

Comment: "for each x in A there is a set B..." what we are looking for is a set in B that doesn't have a corresponding f(x), not the other way around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem here at all: exactly what the diagonal argument said will happen, does happen.

Specifically, if we take the $f$ that you describe, the associated "antidiagonal" set is $$\{x\in\{1,2,3\}: x\not\in f(x)\}=\{1,2,3\}.$$ And indeed, $\{1,2,3\}\not\in ran(f)$ as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Noah Schweber. Just as a quick follow up...why would the proof not apply to all B? It seems that the proof defines any set B such that the conditions hold, and stating that there is no x such that the output is within range. Why does this not apply to all of the sets B that meet the definition? Thanks so much.

Comment: @DaanyalAliAkhtar I'm not sure what you mean. What "conditions" on $B$ do you have in mind, here?

Comment: So essentially, we have B = {x in A s.t. x not in f(x)}. Should this not apply then to every diagonal set where this is true? In the sense of where the contradiction is? If we are defining a type of set B such that it isn't in range of f(x), then shouldn't all B not be within the range?

Comment: Sorry @Noah Schweber, forgot to tag you.